# Prevent phone from converting HTML entities to emojis

Tags: html, css

I am trying to prevent all phones from converting HTML entities to emojis. Currently I am trying `&#x25c0;` and `&#x25b6;` which converts into ◀ and ▶ respectfully.

When viewed on a phone, they will convert into emojis, and will not look like they do in my browser. Is it somehow possible to force the browser to ignore these entities, and simply treat them as normal characters?

```
<div id="on-off">&#x25c0; ON&#183;OFF &#x25b6;</div>
```

That will result in:

◀ ON·OFF ▶

Looks fine on PC and so on, but will make them into emojis on phones.

EDIT:

Adding `&#xfe0e;` (the variation selector I guess?) does not work. I still see them as emojis. `&#x25c0;` turns into `&#x25c0;&#xfe0e;`.

Comment: For what it's worth, they display left and right arrows in Chrome for Android, not emojis. You might be interested in Font Awesome.

Comment: I just opened this in my phone (running CyanogenOS 12.1) and it didn't convert them to emojis. I assume this "phone" you're talking about is an Apple phone specifically?

Comment: Can't reproduce it in my android phone: http://output.jsbin.com/rikotaraxu

Comment: iOS only perhaps. I have iOS emojis installed on my Android phone, which is why I see them on mine as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar So adding `&#xfe0e;` to the end of the HTML entity should work? Because it does not. I still see emojis.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I did. I also tried another browser.

Comment: @Snorlax Reopened the question. Let's see.